# Where can I see tables for RDS instances in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created the RDS instance in AWS console, and I created the table and load the SQL script. Am I able to see the table and data for this RDS instance in AWS console?

Answer (score 44):

No, you cannot see the RDS data (tables, rows, etc.) in the AWS Management Console.

To see the data, you'll need the appropriate client depending on the RDS engine type. Some examples:

- MySQL: MySQL Workbench
- SQL Server: SQL Server Management Studio
- PostgreSQL: pgAdmin
- Oracle: Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 5):

In the RDS query editor:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public';
```

Comment: Note that you can only do this if your RDS DB has the 
Data API enabled. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.enabling

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to achieve, you can use AWS Glue - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QueryEditor to list the tables you've created using this SQL:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'name of your database goes here';
```